# Black screen with X cursor no access to terminal from there

Tags: 13.10

Ubuntu 13 after rebooting I get a black screen with an X cursor without any access to terminals I think. I don't know how to fix or even start fixing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment: "*i tried to do the ctrl alt f2 to access terminal but i just can't log in, i my to enter my user name ang password but it still goes to the black screen with the X cursor. I don't actually manage to input the username and password, it just suddenly goes to the black screen after 1 or 2 seconds.*"

Looks like lightdm is stuck in an endless loop and keep switching back to VT7. Please press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> which will terminate all running processes. After that switch to a virtual console just like Danilo said and try the commands he wrote.

Comment: Thanks! I did that and did what Danilo said but it didn't work. I decided to google and purge nvidia-current and it worked! I forgot I installed nvidia-current a night ago and didn't reboot. Will trying to install nvidia again break my installation again?

Comment: @gnsy I can't tell, you have to try it. Did you use the proprietary drivers before and it was working and just upgraded to a newer version? Or until that time you used the free nouveau driver and tried to replace it with the proprietary one?

Comment: Yeah, I updated nvidia-current again and it got broken again. Purged it again and it's back to normal. I guess i'll  just have to not install nvidia for a while.

Comment: @gnsy But the driver which is working for you is an older proprietary nvidia driver? Or the free nouveau driver? Which one is working? If the latter is the case then try booting with the `nomodeset` kernel parameter.

Answer (score 1):

When rebooting hit <kbd>esc</kbd> to see if ubuntu is loading files, if yes,then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> to open terminal. Put your login and password. And try to re-install unity

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

`sudo apt-get install unity`

worked for me once

Comment: i tried to do the ctrl alt f2 to access terminal but i just can't log in, i my to enter my user name ang password but it still goes to the black screen with the X cursor. I don't actually manage to input the username and password, it just suddenly goes to the black screen after 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: this command you can do even before ubunto fully loads to wellcome screen. did you try that?

Comment: I'm spamming ctrl alt f2 while booting up. I get to see the commandline for less than 2 seconds then it just boots itself up to the black screen with X cursor. It doesn't even give me a chance to log in. Is there a way I can use my ubuntu 13.10 CD to fix this?

Comment: there is an option to reinstall without loosing your files but some times you loose you configuration and installed packages